# Why is my angular service not returning any results

Tags: angularjs

My angular.js service is not returning any results and I can't figure out why. I am not getting any errors and when check the console I cannot see that the server script is being called?

This is my controller function:

```
$scope.getLeads = function() {
            var promise = 
            LeadsSrv.all();
            promise.then(
            function(d) { 
                $scope.leads = d.data;
                console.log(d);
            },
            function(e) {
                $log.error('failure loading leads', e);
            });
        };
        console.log($scope.leads);
```

The service being called is this:

```
LeadApp.factory('LeadsSrv', function($http) {
    return {
        all: function () {
            $http({
                url: '../Data.php',
                method: "POST",
                params: { req_id: 'leads_list', user_id: 1 }
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: because LeadsSrv.all(); is not returning a promise

Comment: can you show me how to achieve that?

Comment: they got it in the answers

Comment: none of the mentioned works...?!

Answer (score 1):

Your `all()` method is not returning anything. Returning from inside `then()` does not return to the outer function. You need to return the `$http` promise itself

Try

```
LeadApp.factory('LeadsSrv', function($http) {
    return {
        all: function () {
          // return `$http` promise
          return  $http({
                url: '../Data.php',
                method: "POST",
                params: { req_id: 'leads_list', user_id: 1 }
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Based on what information? Use browser dev tools network to inspect request itself and also add a `catch()` handler

Answer (score 0):

```
LeadApp.factory('LeadsSrv', function($http) {
    return {
        all: function () {
            return $http({
                url: '../Data.php',
                method: "POST",
                params: { req_id: 'leads_list', user_id: 1 }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Try making the above changes hopefully that will work